# How to use strongly-typed like dictionary <string,Type> to associate a string to a class

Tags: c#

I want to create a dictionary to associate a string to a class for example:

```
"dog" -> Dog class
"cat" -> Cat class
```

so I tried this

```
public Dictionary<String, Type> dic = new Dictionary<String, Type>();
dic.Add("dog", Dog);
```

but Add doesn't accept `Dog`.

So what's the syntax ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In .Net there is a dedicated class, `System.Type`, used to describe classes/structures/enums (any type) in the system.  `Dog` is the class you want this info about, to get it you can either retrieve it using just the `Type` by using `typeof(Dog)`, or--if you have an instance of `Dog`you can use `myDog.GetType();`

Answer (score 14):

You should use the [`typeof`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs(VS.71).aspx) operator to get the corresponding `Type` object:

```
public Dictionary<String, Type> dic = new Dictionary<String, Type>();
dic.Add("dog", typeof(Dog));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public Dictionary<String, Type> dic = new Dictionary<String, Type>();
dic.Add("dog", typeOf(Dog));
```

Answer (score 0):

typeof(Dog) if Dog is an object